# How can I have multiple ASP.NET MVC projects in a single solution? All project share Common layout page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

While working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 application, I have a requirement to use  one project in another project. For example: I have a project A and a project B. I need to use  project B inside of project A. How Project A & B Communicate each other in MVC

Comment: You can use Area in mvc. just google about area

Comment: why you want multiple mvc projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Solution Using MVC Pluggable Architecture

http://geekswithblogs.net/cokobware/archive/2013/01/15/asp.net-mvc-4-pluggable-application-modules.aspx

https://thesoftwarearchitecture.wordpress.com/2013/06/29/pluggable-application-modular-in-asp-net-mvc